# Use maskmoney library on inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form where I add the inputs automatically with a function in js like this:

```js
$('.Preco1').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
$('.Preco1').focus();

$('#sub').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2, suffix: ' € ' });

$(".soma4, .soma5, .soma20").blur(function(){

    var total1 = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var selector = $(this)
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma4").each(function(){
        total1 = total1 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma5").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    selector.closest(".test").find(".soma20").each(function(){
        total2 = total2 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });

    total3 = total * total1;
    total4 = total2 / 100;
    total5 = total3 * total4;
    total6 = total3 - total5;
    selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").val(total6.toFixed(2));
    
    var total3 = 0;

    $(".soma").each(function(){
        total3 = total3 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    
    $("#sub").val(total3.toFixed(2));
      $('#sub').focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp5">
<div class="test">
  <div class="form-group col-md-1"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma4" name="Qttd" id="Qttd" required>
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Qttd">Quantidade</label>       
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="width: 11.099999995%; flex: 0 0 11.099%;max-width: 11.099%;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma5" name="Uniit" id="Uniit" required>
    <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Uniit">Preço Unitário</label>  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma alinha sub3" name="Vallor" id="Vallor" required>
    <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Vallor">Total</label>        
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row fixarfundo">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" >                       
    <input type="text" class="form-control alinha" name="sub" id="sub">
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>                        
    <span class="form-bar"></span>                      
    <label class="label3" for="sub">Total</label>        
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The problem is that when using this line inside the function in js `$('#sub').focus();`, whenever I want to click on the next input I have to double click on the same input to be able to write to that input. Should take the input with just one click

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  Why are you focusing that element if you don't want that element to have focus?  Why not just remove that one "problem line" you've identified if you don't want it to happen?

Comment: @David I'm focusing on the element because I want the element to always have the euro symbol, and if I don't focus it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to focus it to get the euro symbol. Just set `symbolStay` to `true`. Then set the value like this:

```
   $('#sub').maskMoney({ symbolStay: true, decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2, suffix: ' € ' });
   $("#sub").maskMoney('mask', value * 100);
```

(I don't know why you have to multiply it by 100, but you do)

Check this out:

```js
$('.Preco1').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
$('.Preco1').focus();

$('#sub').maskMoney({ symbolStay: true, decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2, suffix: ' € ' });

$(".soma4, .soma5, .soma20").blur(function(){

    var total1 = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var selector = $(this)
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma4").each(function(){
        total1 = total1 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
     selector.closest(".test").find(".soma5").each(function(){
        total = total + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    selector.closest(".test").find(".soma20").each(function(){
        total2 = total2 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });

    total3 = total * total1;
    total4 = total2 / 100;
    total5 = total3 * total4;
    total6 = total3 - total5;
    selector.closest(".test").find(".sub3").val(total6.toFixed(2));
    
    var total3 = 0;

    $(".soma").each(function(){
        total3 = total3 + Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    });
    
    $("#sub").maskMoney('mask',total6 * 100);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" class="limp5">
<div class="test">
  <div class="form-group col-md-1"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma4" name="Qttd" id="Qttd" required>
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Qttd">Quantidade</label>       
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1" style="width: 11.099999995%; flex: 0 0 11.099%;max-width: 11.099%;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1 alinha soma5" name="Uniit" id="Uniit" required>
    <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Uniit">Preço Unitário</label>  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control1 soma alinha sub3" name="Vallor" id="Vallor" required>
    <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
    <span class="form-bar"></span>
    <label class="label3" for="Vallor">Total</label>        
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row fixarfundo">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" >                       
    <input type="text" class="form-control alinha" name="sub" id="sub">
    <span class="form-highlight"></span>                        
    <span class="form-bar"></span>                      
    <label class="label3" for="sub">Total</label>        
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```